# jquery - write a function to allow for a callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript callback programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888488/javascript-callback-programming)

A lot of jquery functions allow for a callback. Most are in a syntax like:

```
$('.selector').slideUp('fast', function(){
    alert('slideUp has completed');
});
```

If I'm writing my own function, how can I make sure it is finished before the one after it is called (i.e. provide a callback parameter)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888488/javascript-callback-programming

Answer (score 5):

```
var foo = function(bar, callback){
  console.log(bar);
  if(typeof callback == "function"){
    callback();
  }
};

foo("hello world", function(){
  console.log("done!");
});
```

#### output

```
hello world
done!
```

---

Alternatively, you can invoke the callback like so

```
callback.call(this, arg1, arg2);
```

This will pass the scope of the `foo` function (and optional parameters) to the callback function.

```
var foo = function(bar, callback){
  console.log(bar);
  if(typeof callback == "function"){
    callback.call(this, bar);
  }
};

foo("hello world", function(x){
  console.log(x + " is done!");
});
```

#### output

```
hello world
hello world is done!
```